# Como esconder dados pessoais no front-end

Tags: api, segurança, lado-do-cliente

Quando a gente quer esconder algum dado pessoal no back-end a gente usa o arquivo `.env`, e depois recupera essas informações usando `process.env.[KEY_NAME]`, porem isso só funciona no back-end pois como o `dotenv` é um modulo do `Node` o browser não consegue executar...

Então como faço para proteger dados q gostaria de manter privado no front-end? Estou tentando esconder minha `API_KEY`, preciso fazer uma requisição pra uma API do tipo `http://url&appid=[MINHA_API_KEY]`, existe algum modo simples de esconder e recuperar essa chave como o `.env` do back-end? É que não quero que essa chave vá para o repositório do `github`, nem fique visível pro usuário através do `developers tools` do browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como. Tudo que trafega entre servidor e navegador é visível pelo usuário de alguma forma. No entanto, você consegue "esconder" essa chave de duas formas:

1. Fazer a requisição para o serviço externo no seu back-end e deixar a chave guardada lá - assim o cliente só se comunica com a sua API, sem saber a chave para o serviço externo
2. Fazer o usuário usar sua própria chave - o que não é viável em todos os casos